# Mobile Survey Design -- Next button vs automatic continue

Tags: mobile, buttons, surveys, questionnaire

I'm wondering if there is a situation in mobile survey design where a next button is more favorable than automatic continue after user selection and vice versa.

Comment: Can you include more detail or context? what do you mean by "mobile survey design"? what is your use case?

Answer (score 1):

If I am interpreting this correctly, you are talking about a survey form where users select from a multiple choice option? If so, I believe having the "next" button is more favorable to prevent user error. If the user accidentally picks option 1 but they wanted option 2, they can change options and hit "next" once they are 100% sure they selected the correct one. If there is no "next" button, the user may select the wrong answer and have no way to correct their mistake

Answer (score 1):

I personally think you should have a next button. While it's an extra touch, it allows the user to confirm that the chosen selection is correct. Additionally, you may have to deal with other form elements, such as checkboxes (multi-select), text entry or even other ideas. While you can have a next button only where it is required, it helps the user when the UI is consistent.